# Django extensions shell_plus with jupyter lab

Tags: django, jupyter-lab, django-extensions

I've been trying to use `./manage.py shell_plus --lab` command but i keep getting following error:

```
...
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-MorsWGAo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 556, in handle
    runner()
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-MorsWGAo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 303, in run_jupyterlab
    self.run_notebookapp(app, options)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-MorsWGAo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 237, in run_notebookapp
    app.initialize(notebook_arguments)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-MorsWGAo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 732, in initialize
    super().initialize()
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-MorsWGAo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 403, in initialize
    raise JupyterServerExtensionException(msg)
jupyter_server.extension.application.JupyterServerExtensionException: This extension has no attribute `serverapp`. Try calling `.link_to_serverapp()` before calling `.initialize()`.
```

I'm using `pipenv` this would be potentially relevant parts of my Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[scripts]
dev = "./scripts/dev.sh"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true

[packages]
Django = "~=3.0.0"
...
django-extensions = "*"
...
[dev-packages]
flake8 = "*"
autoflake = "*"
bpython = "*"
epc = "*"
importmagic = "*"
ipdb = "*"
ipython = "*"
pyls-black = "*"
pyls-isort = "*"
coverage = "*"
werkzeug = "*"
jupyterlab = "*"
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thx in advance.

**EDIT**

Simple workaround would be to use `./manage.py shell_plus --notebook` and then in browser simply navigating to `/lab` and choosing **Django Shell-Plus** in notebooks section.

Comment: I've had the same problem, bumping `django-extensions` to 3.1.2 solved it for me.

Comment: Please read this document [ https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html#ipython-notebook ]